# make4ht creates images for double-dollar formulas despite mathjax option

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, mathjax, make4ht

I want to convert the following (minimized) TeX file to HTML:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
We have $a = a$, \(a = a\) and also
\[c = c\] and even
\begin{equation*}
  E = mc^2.
\end{equation*}
All seems to work, except for
$$F = ma.$$
\end{document}
```

My config file is

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem,booktabs,float,graphicx,hyperref}

\Preamble{xhtml}

\Configure{MathJaxConfig}{{
tex: {
      tags: "ams",
      \detokenize{%
      inlineMath: [ [’$’,’$’], ["\\\(","\\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ [’$$’,’$$’], ["\\[","\\]"] ],}
      processEscapes: true,
      processEnvironments: true,
      packages: [’base’, ’color’, ’ams’, ’boldsymbol’, ’newcommand’, ’verb’]
  }
}}
\Configure{MathjaxSource}{https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js}


\def\eqref#1{$\mathrm{(\ref{#1})}$}

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

and the command I run is

```bash
make4ht -c /CONF/sample.cfg markup.tex "mathjax"
```

Unfortunately, this produces images for every formula that is wrapped between two dollar signs $$. How can I fix this? I have tried to mimic the solutions to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287654/converting-to-html-keeping-equations-as-latex-and-using-dollar-signs) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265815/converting-latex-to-html-using-exsheets-and-keeping-equations-as-latex/265916#265916) answers by Michal by detokenizing everything between two dollar signs but it did not work.

Also, I do not want to use MathML as it does not parse my formulas as good as TeX-to-MathJax.

Comment: someone may provide a make4ht config, but the input latex files should not have `$$` which is not supported latex syntax.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by that. Are you saying make4ht cannot deal with ```$$```?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/107497

Comment: No I am saying `$$` is not latex, if make4ht supports it that is because it is supporting some non-latex primitive tex constructs.

Comment: Ok, I get the point. But the majority does use ```$$``` and I have to account for that. So I preferably need a native make4ht solution. If this is not possible, then I will have to read and replace each opening and closing ```$$``` with ```\[...\]``` manually before feeding the string to make4ht.

Comment: On an up-to-date TL installation (with make4ht version v0.3l), your setup produces no images, i.e `$$F = ma.$$` becomes `  \[F = ma.\]` in the HTML output and is rendered correctly

Comment: as @DG' said, if you have up-to-date TeX Live installation, your code should work (except for the error message caused by `equation*` not defined, you need to use `amsmath`). I've added code to support `$$` few weeks ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work with the up-to-date TeX Live distribution, but you can add the support also using the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\Configure{$$}{\:HandleMathjaxCatcodes}{\:RestoreMathjaxCatcodes}{\expandafter\AltlDisplayDollars}
\long\def\AltlDisplayDollars#1$${\alteqtoks{\[#1\]}$$}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It converts `$$` in your source to `\[` in the output, so you don't even need to provide any configuration to MathJax. This is the resulting HTML code:

```html
<!-- l. 4 --><p class='noindent'>We have \(a = a\), \(a = a\) and also \[c = c\] and even \begin {equation*}  E = mc^2.  \end {equation*} All seems to work, except for
                                 \[F = ma.\]
</p>
```

[image]

Comment: I confirm that the problem was caused by the old version of texlive. As always, thanks a lot michal!